# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: regex

Tags: jquery, syntax-error

IE:
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: regex

Firefox:
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: regex

I see this error in the JS error log, but I've never seen it in my own browser. It only happens in Firefox and IE (various versions), but no other browsers. And it happens on dozens of different pages.

Because it's happening on different pages for a small percentage of our users, but only for IE and Firefox, and because it never happens for me, I feel like it must be a plug-in. If that's the case I'm happy to just ignore the error. But I'd rather only start ignoring the error if I knew for sure that it wasn't something on my end.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd really appreciate the help!

Comment: Code? Libraries you are using? We're not oracles - the more detail the better.

Comment: Well, that's the problem. I have no idea what code is causing this. If you go to any site running jQuery (for example: [link]http://vols.pt ) and then run `$(":regex")` in the console, you can duplicate this error. However, I've grepped our entire codebase and nowhere does the string ":regex" exist. So, it has to be coming from somewhere else. That's what I'm hoping someone can tell me. Make sense?

Comment: Much more sense. Just a thought - if you're using outside libraries, are they being loaded in order (by putting them in <head>) or are they being loaded as-they-can (by putting them in the <body> or by using requirejs)? If the latter, perhaps there's a plugin that needs to be loaded prior to some other piece of code, and that's what is causing the issue.

Comment: We are using requireJS. But, again, I grepped our code base and couldn't find the source of it. We do have ads on the site, so my best guess is that an ad with bad JS (which should include it's own copy of jQuery). Since I usually run Ad Block, I typically don't see them. I was hoping someone else had seen the issue and knew where the offending code came from.

It's not a huge deal, just something I was curious about.

Answer (score 4):

The reason of error is that somewhere is used `$("#xxx:regex")` or `jQuery("#xxx:regex")`. Such code could be generated by `ICEFaces push` for example to execute javascript on client. I had similar problem exactly when tried to execute javascript from `ICEFaces push`. To fix it is enough to comment `":"` like `$("#xxx\\:regex")` in script or `jQuery("#xxx\\\\:regex")` in  `ICEFaces JavaScriptRunner.runScript`

Comment: I'm not sure that this comment is exactly relevant... ICEFaces is some sort of Java Server thing, which we don't use on our site. I understand that something else could be generating this, such as a third party library. However, the first issue is that jQuery doesn't have a pseudo called :regex, so escaping doesn't help. And second, I'd like to figure out what is generating this so I can avoid it.